# Twitter APIのOauth2.0 with PKCEで取得したBearerトークンはいつまで有効ですか？

Tags: twitter, oauth, webapi

Twitter APIのOauth2.0 with PKCEで取得したBearerトークンはいつまで有効ですか？

同じ`Bearerトークン(offline.access)`でも1日経つと有効でなくなってしまい、ツイートの投稿などがAPI経由でできなくなってしまいます。

しかしBearerトークン取得の際には`アクセス権を取り消すまでアカウントにアクセスできます。`というふうに出ています。

[image]

自分の見解としては`Refresh tokens`というものを使用すれば期限が延ばせるという考えなのですが、これは2日間期限を延ばせない期間があって、三日後に`Refresh tokens`を行えば再度Bearerトークンを使用できますか？

Comment: 「2日間期限を延ばせない期間があって」とはどこから来た考えですか？トークン更新のフローは[ドキュメント](https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/authentication/oauth-2-0/user-access-token#:~:text=copied%20to%20clipboard-,Step%205,-%3A%20POST%20oauth2/token)に示されているとおりかと思いますが，通常OAuth2のRefresh Tokenを使用したトークン更新は既存トークンの失効までに可能です(それによって既存トークンが失効されるかだとかは場合によるかもしれませんが)．ところで，"only stay valid for two hours unless you’ve used the `offline.access` scope" とあるので`offline.access`をセットした場合のトークン期限がどうなるかはよくわからないのですが，通常と同じく2時間ではないのですか？

Comment: 「2日間期限を延ばせない期間があって」はTwitter iOSアプリを実装した際に、一定期間アプリが開かれないなどを想定していました。

そこの文の説明だと`offline.acess`を使用しない場合2時間だというふうに考えてのですが、それが間違えているんですかね？

Comment: そういう意味であれば**間に2日間あいてしまっても**その後トークン更新をすれば得られた新しいトークンは利用できるはずですね．2時間の方は手元で確認しできないのでドキュメントから読み取れる以上の情報を持ち合わせていないのでなんとも言えませんが，通常わざわざ分ける必要もなさそう

Comment: 結果が分かりましたので、自己解答で載せておきます。自分の実装ミスにより混乱していたようです。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ドキュメントには以下のようにあるが、実際には`offline.access`でも2時間で`Access Token`の期限は切れてしまうことが確認できました。

> How long will my credentials stay valid?
> By default, the access token you create through the Authorization Code Flow with PKCE will only stay valid for two hours unless you’ve used the offline.access scope.

しかしトークン生成時に出力した`Reflesh Token`を使えば、2時間たっても、新しい`Access Token`を再発行可能のようです。その時にはReflesh Tokenも新しいものになるようです。